# Nuxt.js run production inside docker cannot find module .output/server/index.mjs MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose, nuxt.js

I have like this `docker-compose.yml` file with source code:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  nuxt:
    build:
      context: .
    image: nuxtapp
    container_name: nuxtapp
    command: npm run start
    environment:
    - NODE_ENV=production
    volumes:
    - .:/nuxtapp
    ports:
      - "6666:3000"
```

Dockerfile source code:

```
FROM node:16.20.0-alpine3.18 AS builder
ENV APP_ROOT /nuxtapp

RUN apk add git python3
RUN mkdir ${APP_ROOT} \
    && chown -R node: ${APP_ROOT} \
    && chmod 0750 ${APP_ROOT}

USER node
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}
COPY --chown=node:node ["./package.json", "./package-lock.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install --production

COPY --chown=node . ${APP_ROOT}
RUN set -eux ; \
  npm run build --production && \
  npm cache clean --force && \
  rm -rf .next/cache && \
  rm -rf .nuxt/cache

FROM node:16.20.0-alpine3.18
ENV APP_ROOT /nuxtapp
RUN mkdir ${APP_ROOT} \
    && chown -R node: ${APP_ROOT} \
    && chmod 0750 ${APP_ROOT}

USER node
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}
COPY --from=builder ${APP_ROOT}/ ./
```

When I run my docker compose get error with message:

```
> start
> node .output/server/index.mjs

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1029
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/nuxtapp/.output/server/index.mjs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:871:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)        
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Docker can't access to file `/nuxtapp/.output/server/index.mjs` inside container which generated after run command from Dockerfile:

```
RUN set -eux ; \
  npm run build --production && \
  npm cache clean --force && \
  rm -rf .next/cache && \
  rm -rf .nuxt/cache
```

How I can fix my problem?

Comment: Your `volumes:` block is hiding absolutely everything the Dockerfile does; delete that.  You also do not need to set `container_name:`; you shouldn't need to provide a `command:` override (use the Dockerfile `CMD` instead); you don't need to specify `image:` if you're not pushing to a repository; that particular `environment:` setting might better fit a Dockerfile `ENV` as well.